# Unix Command to Output Line Containing between digits

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep

My question is a command (like grep, awk) that will output lines containing numbers between 3 & 8 digits.

I understand how to match between numbers like matching between 25 & 39 [2-3][5-9], but I don't understand how to output lines containing between a certain number of digits.

---

Input:

```
1234567
1234 
abc
1234567890
1
1AB2345C
```

Output:

```
1234567
1234 
1AB2345C
```

Comment: 1AB2345C is not a number

Comment: @hjpotter92 I know that, I just want to count between a specified number of digits in a line. The line can contain anything else. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk one-liner does it:

```
awk '{s=$0}{n=gsub(/[0-9]/,"",s)}n>=3&&n<=8' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "1234567
1234 
abc
1234567890
1
1AB2345C"|awk '{s=$0}{n=gsub(/[0-9]/,"",s)}n>=3&&n<=8' 
1234567
1234 
1AB2345C
```

Explanation

```
awk                   #awk is a cli powerful text processing tool
'{s=$0}               #read one line, assign to variable s,(leave $0 untouched)
{n=gsub(/[0-9]/,"",s)}#replace all numbers of s to empty,
                      #return the count of replacement was done, assign it to n
n>=3&&n<=8'           #if n between 3 and 8, print the line ($0)
```

if the explanation doesn't help you to understand the command, please read man/info gawk.

Comment: How is it counting digits? Isn't it just counting the number of characters on a line. For example is a Line said: "This is a Test 1234" this command would not work. But that line still has between 3 & 8 digits.

Comment: @user3211189 Oh, I think I misunderstood your requirement, I would update the answer soon

Comment: @user3211189 check the new answer

Comment: Would you mind explaining the command. I don't understand it. Thanks again

Comment: @user3211189 which part should I explain?

Comment: All of of it, but especially what gsub is. Sorry I'm a novice

Comment: @user3211189 This will be true even if number are not togeather, so this will hit to `45 is this ok 23 end` since there are `4` digits in the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by deleting all non-digits and then check line-length, e.g. here with `tr` and `awk`:

```
<infile tr -cd '0-9\n' | awk 'length >= 3 && length <= 8'
```

Output:

```
1234567
1234
12345
```